# Is it possible to make a PCB vibrate by pulsing traces?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, ultrasound, vibration

I want to make a PCB vibrate at ultrasonic frequencies like in the [TI's lens cleaning demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0kbt2XC5qg).

Is it possible to make a PCB vibrate by pulsing the PCB traces at high frequencies?

Comment: Yes, if you add a magnet nearby, not attached to the PCB. But the PCB mass and size may limit how fast it can vibrate. Flexible PCB would be best bet.

Comment: Just make sure [it doesn't take so much current that you could solder with it.](https://hackaday.com/2023/01/18/internal-heating-element-makes-these-pcbs-self-soldering/)

Comment: Do note the the PCB in the video is not the component that vibrates, it is the driver board for an ultrasonic transducer.  See the output connector at the bottom of the board marked with "OUTPUT 0-250Vp,  3.5A, 40-400kHz", this is where ultrasonic transducer wiring is connected.  Here is an example of a popular ultrasonic kit that shows the transducer and driver board:  https://www.amazon.com/Ultrasonic-Cleaning-Transducer-Cleaner-Driver/dp/B078MKN29W

Comment: Can you be clear about what "pulsing" means in this context?

Comment: @Andyaka I meant switching a PCB trace on high frequencies and high current probably

Answer (score 1):

NEC 300.3 and NEC 300.20. These are rules to minimize vibration from electrical wiring in buildings. Normally I don't advise violating the electrical codes, but... brak all those rules :)

Yeah, it's just a matter of coming up with a coil on the PCB. The biggest trick would be routing the current so it all flows in the same direction. Then have something for it to react against, e.g. another PCB.

Comment: Or another coil on the opposite side of the PCB with the current flowing in the opposite direction.

Comment: Rules for building electrical wiring for building electrical wiring. This isn't building electrical wiring.